# Files disappear in Ubuntu One for Android

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I use the Ubuntu One Apps for my Samsung Galaxy Ace. Since the last update I have the following problem:

When I download a file from a folder and it failed ( because I lose connection or something else), then I can retry downloading it, because this file disappears in the list.
After a restart it also isn't there. On my computer the file exists and in the online interface, too. When I move another file in the same folder, then the missing file is back.

Is there a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug, which will be fixed in the upcoming update. It's related to directory file listing caching. Could you please verify if you can download download that file from Ubuntu One website? If not, there's another problem we need to have a look at. Thanks!

PS Re: to the other answer - yes, clearing app data will fix the problem, only once. Plus, it'll wipe the info about which files have been already downloaded.

Comment: Good info, I've up-voted this answer so it should appear first from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the app data on the phone. Go to `Menu /Settings /Applications/ Manage applications /Ubuntu One Files` and touch Clear data. You may have to re-enter your settings and password, so make sure you have these available or backed up first.
[image: Phone screenshot]